Why is the Autodesk BIM RFI API returning "you are not allowed to use this api" with 2-Legged Token?
I am unable to get a list of RFIs using 2-Legged token.  I am an account admin and do have access to the project in the browser.  However, when I try to get the same information programmatically, I get "you are not allowed to use this api".  However, other API calls are working.  The only difference is that this call requires a "x-user-id".  What am I missing?
I am able to generate a 2-Legged token:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token
I can take the token and get a list of hubs:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs
I can get the project Id:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/xxx/projects
I can even find my UID:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/xxx/users
However, when I try to RFIs by container:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/rfis/v2/containers/xxx/rfis
I get 403 forbidden and the following:
{
"title": "you are not allowed to use this api"
}
My user is an account admin.  Why am I not allowed to use the API?

Could you please take a look at this documentation?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/rfis-v2-rfis-GET/
You will notice that you can only use 3LO to retrieve RFI list. 2LO is not supported.
